# Which other word can I use instead of "bet"

Tags: word-request, translation, french

I'm developing an application about gambling and I need an other word than "bet".

The users can create their own bets then every other players can place a bet on a proposition. For example :

> Would I get my degree ? Yes/No

Players can then place a bet on Yes or No.

Here is the sentence I'm trying to translate from French :

> Placer une mise sur un pari

Basically, "pari" and "mise" can be translated by "bet". For example :

**Pari :**

> Je te fais le pari que je peux aller là-haut = I bet you I can get up there

**Mise :**

> Je mise sur ce cheval-ci = I place a bet on this horse

On the application, there is a list of "bets" displayed. They can then place a bet on them. But because I'm already using the word "bet" to say "placer une mise (place a bet)" I need another word to say "pari".

I was wondering about the word "gamble" but I'm not sure this can be a good translation in this context. Basically, the players would place a bet on a gamble. Is it a correct sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"wager" is a common synonym for "bet" and will mean the same thing in this context.

"gamble" doesn't quite work here, because gambling *involves* placing bets, but also involves other things such as the decision-making process behind the bet, the rules of the game, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to do a word-for-word literal translation. In English, we don't say "bet on a bet".

Another word to consider is **wager**. I would use something like, "Make a wager (on the outcome)".

Comment: Thanks ! So I can say "place a bet on the outcome of a bet" ?

Comment: @M.Ozn You really don't need the last part "of a bet". It is redundant.

Comment: Oh sorry, I made a mistake. I mean, "Make a wager on the outcome of a bet" ?

Comment: @M.Ozn Still clunky. Not very idiomatic. People say "wager on the outcome of a race/election/game".